# How to output json to a single textview not in a listview

Tags: android, json, textview

kinda new to android. I am outputing json to a listview and it is working, now my problem is how do i output a single textview that is not in a listview?

Here is my code

```
private void showResult1(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY1);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String ss_update_time = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ss_update_time);
                HashMap<String,String> match = new HashMap<>();
                match.put(Config.TAG_ss_update_time, ss_update_time);
                list.add(match);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Standings.this, list, R.layout.standings,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_ss_update_time},
                new int[]{ R.id.ss_update_time});
        TextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

I dont know what to change in the setAdapter. It just gives me a red error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your JSON response into a String and then set it in your textView. It may look like this.

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);    
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (HashMap<String, String> elementInList : list) {
                for (String value : elementInList.values()) {
                    stringBuilder.append(value);
                }
            }
            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Yes but first you need to get a reference of your textView. see the edited

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: ListAdapter is an object used to work with ListView. You don't need to create List Adapter to display Json string using TextView.
So to show String output you just need to do this:

```
TextView.setText(some_string_variable);
```

Hope I have understood you correctly.

Comment: what should i put inside ()? because it is giving me an error sir